# htaccess Redirect URL of Subdirectories managed through CMS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, content-management-system, seo

All the urls of our site are written `www.mydomain.com/sub1/cms/pagename`

Through the CMS we can specify `pagename`

`sub1`  and `cms`  are not actually directories on the server.

We need to change the pagenames to be more SEO friendly, but we still want any traffic to the old pagename to direct to the new one.

I have tried making an .htaccess file specifying:

```
Redirect 301  /sub1/cms/oldpagename mydomain.com/sub1/cms/newpagename
```

but it does not work.

I have been successful with:

```
Redirect 301  /oldpagename mydomain.com/sub1/cms/newpagename
```

Can this be done somehow through .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your 301 redirect rules for redirect use a full url including the http:// portion.

```
Redirect 301 /sub1/cms/oldpagename http://mydomain.com/sub1/cms/newpagename
```

Second, it sounds to me like your CMS  has put a rewrite rule in place to handle the /sub1/cms/pagename style urls.   If this rule comes before your redirect, your redirect will never get triggered.  Try moving your redirect to the top of the .htaccess file.

Comment: Ok, I have included http:// I just had to leave it out in order to post here because stackoverflow picked it up as a link.  I will try putting this rule first, is it possible to override the rules implemented by the cms?

Comment: Yes, if the rule is first, it should be the the one that is used.

Comment: Putting your urls in code blocks prevents this site from hot linking them.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about inserting urls.  The problem is that the cms rules for directing the pagename is not delegated through .htaccess but through a series of xsl stylesheets. I found this post which may be along the lines of what I need to do: http://getsymphony.com/discuss/thread/31007/2/  For right now the xsl template match is written as follows: <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>